# Module categories over $Rep(G)$.

Tags: fusion-categories, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

Related to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3309/are-there-two-groups-which-are-categorically-morita-equivalent-but-only-one-of-wh) I also had some troubles to understand the classification of module categories over $Rep(G)$. Specifically, on page 12 of  Ostrik's [paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0111/0111139v1.pdf) what is the category $\mathrm{Rep}^1(\tilde{H})$? $k^\*$ acting as "identity character on V" means $a.v=av$ for all $a \in k^*$ and $v \in V$? Then what is the structure of module category over $Rep(G)$? Tensor product should be after restricting representations of $G$ to $H$ and then inducing back to $\tilde{H}$?

Concretely, I was thinking about the following example. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then $Rep(H)$ is a module category over $Rep(G)$ via tensor product as $H$-modules. What is the decomposition of $Rep(H)$ in indecomposable module categories and what are the corresponding subgroups $H$ and cocyles $\omega \in H^2(H,\;k^*)$ for each indecomposable subcategory?

Comment: I'd think tensor product is by pulling back a representation from $G$ to $\tilde H$ and then tensoring over $\tilde H$.

How is $\mathcal M$ a module category?

Comment: One rstricts a rep. of $G$ to $H$ and then it tensors over $H$ with some rep. from $\mathcal{O}$. The irreducible constituents of the tensor product are in the same orbit, $\mathcal{O}$.


Comment: @ Leonid: It gives a classification of all modules categories over $Rep(G)$. Maybe I should have said this in the post.

Comment: @Sebastian Burciu: Are they? Take $G=H$ and $\mathcal O$ to be the orbit of the one-point orbit of the trivial representation of $G$, for instance. Aren't you saying that the tensor product of the trivial representation and any representation is trivial? 

Comment: @ t3suji : Yes, it's something wrong. I will rewrite the second part, shortly. One can also take $N=Z(G)$ to get a contradiction. 

Comment: @t3suji: Here is what I had in mind before. Take the orbit $\mathcal{O}$ and induce it up to $G$. All the irreducible constituents that are obtained in this way generate a module category over $Rep(G/N)$. This is also indecomposable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sebastian: your definition of Rep^1(\tilde H) is absolutely correct. If you have
a representation of G you can restrict it to H and consider it as a representation
of \tilde H (this operation is called inflation). Now you can tensor it with any
representation of \tilde H; this tensoring preserves Rep^1(\tilde H); this is 
a module category structure (same thing was explained above by t3suji).

The category Rep(H) considered as a module category over Rep(G) is indecomposable.
It corresponds to subgroup H and trivial cocycle \omega (so \tilde H is a direct product
of H and multiplicative group G_m).